# Surround string elements with " not using any loops

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

Is it possible to do it without loops - If I have a string like: `"ololo with=1 dddd with=2 blablabla"` to `"ololo with='1' dddd with='2' blablabla"` ?

Comment: Puzzle questions may be ok on codegolf SE. For SO you should clarify what code does not work for you and why, also what alternatives you'd like to see (clearly iterating sequence *without loop* of some kind is not possible, but sometimes you can *hide* iteration by using some library methods/classes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If "*without loops*" means "without *explicit* loops" you can use *regular expressions*:

```
  String source = "ololo with=1 dddd with=2 blablabla";
  // surround numbers by apostrophes: 1 -> '1', 123 -> '123'
  String result = Regex.Replace(source, @"\d+", 
    (MatchEvaluator) ((match) => "'" + match.Value + "'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with some clever regular expressions and [Regex.Replace Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: even if  with= 100500 ? (any number)

Comment: Yes, with any number :) Please see answer by Dmitry Bychenko above